# setOnLongClickListener causes UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

When I add this line of code in my Activity

```
    findViewById(R.id.btFilter).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            ResultadoBuscaMapa.this.finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I cannot compile, and get this error

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext
at com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:46)
...
```

in both **Intellij IDEA** and **Android Studio** (latest versions)

Funny thing is that it's an old code and worked just fine until yesterday.

Is it possible that Android Studio broke something in my project structure?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange as it my seem, after the last update of **Android Studio**, the error just vanished in **BOTH** IDE's. Now it runs fine also in **Intellij IDEA**

Answer (score 0):

Where do you declare this listener ? It's better to do `ContextView.findViewById(R.id.btFilter);` 
And i usually declare my widget before setting a listener:

```
Button filter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btFilter);
filter.setOnLongClickListener(....
```

Another way, do you try without `ResultadoBuscaMapa.this.finish();` cause error seems to be link to your context.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's declare in `onCreate` but it's a compile time error, it does not matter if declare the button first (I tried that anyways), also getting rid o the `ResultadoBuscaMapa.this.finish()` did not help.